# Generate 1 report based on multiple executions of stored procedure (passing different parameters to same procedure)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS report that takes a parameter and executes a stored procedure to generate a report with it.
the parameter is a values from a table that I have user select from a dropdown
let's say 15 options that are passed as parameters to each execution.

```
AAAA
AAAB
AAAC
...etc
```

is there any way I can setup the report so it will execute with each parameter and generate a report?

the issue is that now the user has to manually select 1st parameter, generate the report and then export the file result to excel.

what I want to do is a way for the user to select multiple parameters and export just one file containing all of them (the stored procedure can't take more parameters because of the way is coded depends on receiving one parameter only)

so it would have to schedule multiple executions of the stored procedure to create the report and then export this. is this possible? (as a note, the amount of parameters will change frequently so I need to give the option of selecting multiples from a list that is populated from a query to database)

and to clarify, the Stored Procedure needs to take only one parameter, this is not to be solved by sending multiple parameters to operate by using a splitter or similar, as the parameter received by the SP is used in calculations depending of order, (to not go into detail with the SP, just need to take one parameter per execution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already have a report that handles a single option then you can do this easily using sub reports. Don't worry about the length of this answer it actually quite simple.

*I would make a copy of the existing report to be safe...*.

Change the existing report to only accept a single parameter value if if doesn't already. Save this report, this will be your sub-report so let's say it's called `mySubReport`

Next create a new blank report.

Add a dataset (called say `dsParameterList`) that will give you the list of options you want the user to choose from (I guess this will be the same as your current report?). For example if it was a list of companies it might look something like `SELECT CompanyID, CompanyName FROM myCompanyTable`

Next add a parameter called say `@options`, make sure it is set to be multi-value and set the available values to use a query and point this to `dsParameterList`. Set the value and label fields as required.

Now create another dataset called `dsLoop` for example. This dataset will contain a list of selected parameter values. Using the company example from earlier the dataset query might look something like this. `SELECT CompanyID, CompanyName FROM myCompanyTable WHERE CompanyID IN (@options)`

Next add a table to your report and remove columns so that only 1 remains. Set the dataset property of the table/tablix to `dsLoop`. This means we will generate 1 row for every selected parameter value.

In the detail row right click in remaining textbox and choose 'Insert Subreport'. Now right-click the subreport placeholder and set the properties to point to the report we saved earlier (`mySubReport` in this example).

Whilst still in the sub report properties, click the parameters tab and add a new entry, choose the parameter in the left column and set the value in the right column to be the value from `dsLoop` that you want to pass to the subreport. In our company example this would probably be `[CompanyID]`

That's it. You run the report and choose from the parameter list, when you click View Report the `dsLoop` query runs and gives us a list of just those selected Companies, the report body is generated with a row for every row in the `dsLoop` dataset which in turn runs the subreport with a different parameter passed in each time.

**Optionally** You can right-click the rowgroup under the main design window and set the 'pagename' property to a value. In the Company example this might be `=Fields!CompanyName.Value`. When the report is exported to Excel each sheet in the workbook will be named with the name of Company

Comment: this was exactly what I needed and was explained beautifully. even the "optional" part has what would be my next step. this is great, thank you!